# Open dropdown based on selected option

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently the `onClick` method is toggling open class, showing 3 dropdown at one time.

I want to open the dropdown for the selected option, 1 dropdown at a time.

```
methods: {
        onClick: function(event) {
            this.is_open = !this.is_open;
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bs9Lh73m/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with that approach is you need to be able to distinguish three different states, one for each button. Here's an approach that changes to tracking which of the items should be currently displayed by index:

http://jsfiddle.net/bs9Lh73m/2/

```
<label for="i_{{$index}}" v-on="click : onClick($index)">{{ model.type }}</label>
<div class="item_details" v-class="open : $index == openedCount">
    <span>Count
         <select v-model="modelCount">
             <option v-repeat="count : model.features[0].count" value="{{ count.int }}">
                 {{ count.int }}
             </option>
         </select>
    </span>
</div>
```

and

```
onClick: function ($index) {
    this.openedCount = $index;
}
```

The `$index == openedCount` is a conditional that will resolve to true or false which is what is needed to get `v-class` to apply the class. `$index` is a special Vue variable which is set in the current model by `v-repeat`. I added a property called `openedCount` that indicates which button should currently be considered to be opened. The `onClick` call uses `$index` to update this value.

Comment: Can you please share about this bits : v-class="open : $index == openedCount

Comment: Added some explanation for you.